# warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation on creating a a custom Selenium ExcpectedCondition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a custom Selenium explicit wait with the following code

```
class TabsOpened implements ExpectedCondition {     
int expectedTabs;
  
public TabsOpened(int exp) {
  this.expectedTabs = exp;  
}
  
@Override
public Boolean apply(Object driver) {       
  ArrayList<String> allWindowHandles = new ArrayList<> (((WebDriver)driver).getWindowHandles()); 
  return allWindowHandles.size()== this.expectedTabs;
} 
}
```

then

```
wait.until(new TabsOpened(2));
```

But I am getting these warnings while compilation

```
Note: Tests.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Compiling with -Xlint:unchecked flag I get

```
Tests.java:116: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method until in class FluentWait is applied to given types
            wait.until(new TabsOpened(2));  // Wait 3 seconds or until 2 tabs are opened
                      ^
  required: Function<? super T,V>
  found: TabsOpened
  where T,V are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in class FluentWait
    V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
Tests.java:116: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            wait.until(new TabsOpened(2));  // Wait 3 seconds or until 2 tabs are opened
                       ^
  required: Function<? super T,V>
  found:    TabsOpened
  where T,V are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in class FluentWait
    V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
```

Any ideas on how to fix that? I am using Selenium 2.53

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework but according to the [interface javadoc](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html), you should write `implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean>` and the parameter of the overridden method should be of type `WebDriver`, not `Object`.

Comment: I had a compilation error when I used WebDriver object as a parameter that why I changed it to object. However adding  implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean> and changing the parameter back to WebDriver fixes the warning. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, Thanks!

Comment: Done. That happens because this interface extends the interface function with hard typed input for web driver and asks you to declare just the output. If you don't declare the output, the association with the parent interface is not done and so the parameter must be of type object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this framework but according to the [javadoc of the interface you are extending](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html), you should write `implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean>` and the parameter of the overridden method should be of type `WebDriver`, not `Object`.